# Regex to strings that end with a particular substring

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use regex to find all instances of a word "foo" that doesn't end with ".bar".

For example:

foo
foo1
foo.bar

In the example above, I want "foo" and "foo1", but not "foo.bar".  Further, I'm looking to do this using the regex capabilities of Notepad++ and am unsure of the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex. It uses a negative lookahead to disallow the string `foo` from matching when followed by the string `.bar`.

```
\bfoo(?!\.bar)
```